# Print current script name in vBulletin template

Tags: php, vbulletin

Is there any easy way to get current script name in vBulletin template?

I have tried using this but not working -

```
<if condition="THIS_SCRIPT != ''">
    var current_page = 'THIS_SCRIPT';
</if>
```

All I want to store current page type to some JavaScript variable but it was working fine in condition tag but not in direct use.

I have also tried -

```
{vb:raw THIS_SCRIPT} // not working
{vb:var THIS_SCRIPT} // not working
```

Please help!

**# Progress:**

Found a very tricky solution but works!

```
<if condition="$templateName = THIS SCRIPT"></if>
<script>
    var pbj_condition = '$templateName';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
var pbj_condition = '{vb:raw this_script}';
```

:)